# Visual studio auto complete and commas

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, editor

after moving from netbeans to visual studio 2012, theres a feature of the editor i cant seem to find and it saves a lot of time (1 key), it is the following:

Say you are typing a function call or definition or something like, this.doSomething(someString), note that doSomething autocompletes when i see it in the small popup and press '(' which also auto completes the closing ')'. Now im only left to type the parameters inside, i proceed to write someString, and here comes the problem! Now the cursor is in ....(someString|) so i have to move 1 right and then write the ';'. However, in netbeans i could simply write the ';' and it would correctly place it at the end of the line, im not sure if im explaining myself...

this.doSomething(someString;)   ==> This is what i get in VStudio and i dont like
this.doSomething(someString);   ==> This is what i want.

Answer (score 0):

you can go to the end of the line with TAB.

Write "this.d", type TAB complete to

```
this.doSomething
```

type "(" obtain

```
this.doSomething()
```

then write "someS" and TAB complete to

```
this.doSomething(someString)
```

cursor is between "g" and ")". Type TAB again and cursor go after ")". Complete with ";"

```
this.doSomething(someString);
```

So, you have type "this.d TAB (someS TAB TAB ;"

There is no way to do what you exactly want, but with TAB you can save much typing.

Comment: So many tabs, isnt there any addon/plugin to obtain what im looking for? Such a good program and missing this tiny feature makes me sad.